# Java - MapStruct : custom property of Mapper like `nullValueCheckStrategy`

Tags: java, mapstruct

Can I add a new property in interface `Mapper.java` like `nullValueCheckStrategy` for check the permission?

If I added `nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS`
Code Generates will add `if(filed != null)` for every field.

And I want to have a if too like `if(rightService.hasRole("Admin") { ... }` to avoid update the value for a user who hasn't the permission.

It is the first time I ask a question here, I hope to get some answers, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not supported. However, you can achieve that by writing your custom mapper and providing different methods for the different roles that you have. Your mapper could look like:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class MyMapper {

    private MyService service;

    public void update(Target target, Source source) {
        if (service.hasRole("Admin")) {
            updateForAdmin(target, source);
        } else if (service.hasRole("X")) {
            updateForX(target, source);
        }
    }


    //Mappings for Admin, ignore those that he / she has no rights
    protected abstract updateForAdmin(@MappingTarget Target target, Source source);

    //Mappings for X, ignore those that he / she has no rights
    protected abstract updateForX(@MappingTarget Target target, Source source);

    //setter injection
}
```

The basic idea is that you provide a method with the appropriate mappings for each of the roles. The mapper has a single public method and the rest are just there for MapStruct to implement.

Comment: Thanks I will try it.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked for you. Otherwise, let me know and I can update it

Comment: I think it is not ok for me, because your solution is ignore the fields that he has no rights, so we need send different request for that. But I want work with the same request who has all the infos, and backend will test if he has no right, we can't use his value and need to get the old value from data base to avoid modify it.

Comment: Well the `Target` object is already the one from the database, you are performing an update. When ignoring a value during an update method it means that the old value is kept and the one from the request is ignored.

Comment: yes, something like this. I do it with the code fix in the `afterMapping`. If `user.hasRight()` we keep the value from `DTO`, otherwise I need to get the old value from data base and replace his value. But I want to do it with a generic method, it is hard for me.